# vb6 Capture Entire Web Page

Tags: vb6, browser, webbrowser-control

Hey all, I've been trying to find the code that allowed me to capture an entire web page using the webbrowser1 control and i believe also a picturebox or 2.. but i am not able to find the code that i used a couple months ago! I've been goodgling until I'm all googled out!

If anyone knows of the code for VB6 then please post a link to it!.

Thanks,

David

Comment: Do you mean capture an entire web page as an image?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the HTML source? If so you can add a reference to the Microsoft HTML obj Library and;

```
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
set doc = YourWebBrowserCtrl.Document
msgbox doc.documentElement.outerHTML
```

However this will not return the exact source as at this point its been parsed by IE. (It also won't include doc type or anything else preceding the opening `<html>` tag.

If you do want the source, add an internet transfer control and just call .openURL to get the full content.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim DrawSize As New Size(1024, 768)
Using MyBrowser As New WebBrowser
    MyBrowser.ScrollBarsEnabled = False
    MyBrowser.Size = DrawSize
    MyBrowser.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
    While MyBrowser.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    Using myBitmap As New Bitmap(DrawSize.Width, DrawSize.Height)
    MyBrowser.DrawToBitmap(myBitmap, New Rectangle(New Point(0, 0), DrawSize))
        myBitmap.Save("C:\test.jpeg")
    End Using
End Using
```