# how can be captured (import) displayed record in another web in my application using PHP or VB6

Tags: php, vb6

I am developing a system in which I have to capture (and import) records displayed on another website.

The problem scenario is that workers from Saudi Arabia and Qatar, Nepal send messages through a businessman's web site.

I want to capture those messages from the businessman's web site and depending on the message, the application can recharge their Nepali mobile in home.

My question is how can I capture the data using PHP or VB6?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3438918/588306) and other similar questions for examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Get a html page content using Inet in vb6 and put the content in a TextBox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566775/how-to-get-a-html-page-content-using-inet-in-vb6-and-put-the-content-in-a-textbo) and [How can I make Web Scraper Application using Visual Basic 6.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399647/how-can-i-make-web-scraper-application-using-visual-basic-6-0?lq=1).